# Looking for Chrome extension which can make gifs (animated) from browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

I want a good extension/user script which would be able to capture screen (selected area) and then join these captured images into animated gif.

Is there one?

Comment: That is some complicated task for Chrome ... :)

Comment: And for firefox? Or other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You could try: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-gif-capture/algmheobonijciecgfbapkhoonnhlnpe. It's a chrome extension that allows you to do it.

Comment: As of 9/JUN/2014 the extension isn't working on Chrome 35 on Ubuntu 13.10, and has [comments](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/support/algmheobonijciecgfbapkhoonnhlnpe?hl=en&gl=GB#bug) from windows users too

Comment: The extension's URL is dead. There's an [issue](https://github.com/superalex/super-gif-capture/issues/3) dealing with the inactivity of the project. Someone has forked and made some improvements but there does not seem to be any release of these improvements as an extension that can be installed from the web store. @Alex Note that if you happen to be the author of the extension, you *must* disclose this fact in the answer you post here. (See [the page on promotion](https://superuser.com/help/promotion).)

Answer (score 0):

While there aren't any extensions that I know, there is a host of applications that create animated gifs.  Besides the Photoshop, you can also download Advanced Gifeditor, MS GIF animator.

You can also use Paint.net and GIMP. As far as grabbing screen clips, you can use the Windows built in Snag it.  Or a large host of applications that exist for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (chrome extension). It supports image capture, video recording and its gif formation. Check [this](http://blogs.techsmith.com/news-events/snagit-for-chrome-gif-maker/) for details.

Comment: This reads a lot like spam as the linked application is commercial software. Can you edit your post to indicate whether you're affiliated with the developer of the product and explain why this would be a better solution?